# node dateformat throws Invalid date error on Bitnami Mean Stack

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mean-stack, bitnami

Running a custom node app on a Google Cloud Platform Bitnami MEAN stack.  It uses dateformat and keeps returning an error about an Invalid date.  It looks like the issue might be with the date timestamp that is created. Code looks like the following:

```
dateFormat(new Date().getTime(), "dddd, mmmm dS yyyy, h:MM TT");
```

which for me right now is:

dateformat 1481054683108, "dddd, mmmm dS yyyy, h:MM TT"

which throws a Invalid Date error from any dateformat request regardless of Bitnami stack.

So my guess is the problem is more around how a new Date() value is generated on the system.  Anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My Mongoose Schema defined my timestamp value as a String not a Date. Changing it to a Date fixed my issue.